# Shell script to open an application and kill itself without closing application

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script to open chrome with some custom arguments:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --use-system-ssl --use-spdy=off
```

I need to run this and immediately close the process running it without killing chrome. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your script was run_chrome. Then you could do `{run_chrome &} && disown;`

Comment: there IS something like "disown". Thats what I needed, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just run it in background/fork:

```
#/bin/sh
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --use-system-ssl --use-spdy=off &
```